# How to handle <UKN> tokens in text generation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, word2vec, recurrent-neural-network

In my text generation dataset, I have converted all infrequent words into the token  (unknown word), as suggested by most text-generation literature.

However, when training an RNN to take in part of a sentence as input and predict the rest of the sentence, I am not sure how I should stop the network from generating  tokens.
When the network encounters an unknown (infrequent) word in the training set, what should its output be?

**Example:**
Sentence: `I went to the mall and bought a <ukn> and some groceries`
Network input: `I went to the mall and bought a`
Current network output: `<unk> and some groceries`
Desired network output: `??? and some groceries`

What should it be outputting instead of the `<unk>`?

I don't want to build a generator that outputs words it does not know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A RNN will give you a sampling of tokens that are most likely to appear next in your text. In your code you choose the token with the highest probability, in this case «unk».

In this case you can omit the «ukn» token and simply take the **next most likely token** that the RNN suggests based on the probability values that it renders.

Comment: But during RNN training, should we expect the RNN to output <UKN> tokens? It seems weird that we would train the network to output <UKN> but then discard these tokens when actually generating text.

Comment: It's hard to tell without much more detail about your use case. But either you get value out of keeping the unknowns (then use them for training and inference) or not (skip them in training and don't worry while generating). I can imagine that your model works syntactically more correct if you keep the «ukn»'s and replace these in a meaningful way during inference. But again – only an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen `<UNK>` occasionally, but never `<UKN>`.

Even more common in word-embedding-training is dropping rare words entirely, to keep vocabularies compact, and avoid having words-without-sufficient-examples from serving as 'noise' in the training of other words. (Folding them all into a single magic unknown-token – which then becomes *more frequent* than real tokens! – would just tend to throw a big unnatural pseudo-word with no clear meaning into every other word's contexts.)

So, I'm not sure it's accurate to describe this as "suggested by most text-generation literature". And to the extent it might be, wouldn't any source suggesting this then also suggest what-to-do when a prediction is the `UNK` token?

If your specific application needed any real known word instead, even if the NN has low confidence that the right word is any known-word, it would seem you'd just read the next-best-non-`<UKN>` prediction from the NN, as suggested by [@petezurich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51913706/how-to-handle-ukn-tokens-in-text-generation/51915254#51915254).

Comment: Wouldn't dropping unknown tokens produce syntactically incorrect sentences? In the example you'd get `I went to the mall and bought a and some groceries`.

Comment: Yes, but at least for word2vec-style word vectors, that doesn't hurt. Indeed dropping rare tokens below some `min_count` occurrences, & randomly discarding some overly-frequent tokens (as controlled by the `sample` parameter in many libraries) usually *helps* word-vector quality for most typical applications, even though such steps create non-grammatical training input. (Generating actually-plausible grammatical text requires more than just word-cooccurrence-driven & grammar-oblivious word2vec, & I'd suspect there, plug tokens based on parts-of-speech more likely to help than generic `<UNK>`.)

Comment: Oh, I see that your answer relates to learning word vectors. I guess in that context ordering isn't so important so dropping low information words doesn't hurt? But for modeling prose, I don't think you can do that.

Comment: It might not hurt as much as you think. But yes, if you're trying to model grammar, you might want to (1) use a plug word based on deduced part-of-speech (eg `<NOUN>`, `<ADJ>`, etc, or more specific if possible); (2) make a replacement based on some external lexicon of synonyms; (3) drop examples which include any mystery words (or words where the above hacks aren't possible) entirely from the training set.