# what is best solution for setting 'unknown' or 'unk' word vector in word2vec?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

I usually set unk'value as random distribution vector or 0-vector.
It performed not bad,but most situation it's also not best for many task,i think.
But i'm curious about the best method to process 'unk' word vector,thank for any helpful advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle <UKN> tokens in text generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51913706/how-to-handle-ukn-tokens-in-text-generation)

Answer (score 0):

If you're training word-vectors, the most-common strategy is to discard low-frequency terms entirely. (That's what the `min_count` setting does, in Google's original `word2vec.c`, Python gensim `Word2Vec`, etc.)

Whether you'd need to remember that *something* was at a particular place would be more common in sequence-learning scenarios, rather than plain word2vec. (If that's your concern, you could make your question more specific about why & how you're using word-vectors.)